Submit buttons confused when 2 forms on a single modal in Ruby/Rails
I have been searching but have not found an answer for this Ruby/Rails question.  I have a drain_admin haml modal which works fine as long a one of the "render partial" lines is commented out.  When both partials are as below, the submit button for one partial seems to be submittng the other partial.  Can you have a modal in Rails with 2 forms on it?
drain_admin.html.haml
= form_for :thing, :url => things_path, :method => :put, :html => {:id => "adoption_form"} do |f|
  = f.hidden_field "id"

  %fieldset.form-group
  = render partial: 'things/free' 
.break 
  = render partial: 'things/rename

/app/views/things/_free.html.haml
= form_for :thing, :url => things_path, :method => :put, :html => {:id => "free_form"} do |f|
  = f.hidden_field "id"
  = f.hidden_field "user_id", :value => ""
  = f.hidden_field "adopted_name", :value => ""
  %fieldset.form-group
    = f.submit t("buttons.free", :thing => t("defaults.thing")), :class => "btn btn-primary btn-block"

app/views/things/_rename.html.haml
= form_for :thing, :url => things_path, :method => :put, :html => {:id => "adoption_form"} do |f|
  = f.hidden_field "id"
  = f.hidden_field "user_id", :value => @thing.user_id
  %fieldset.form-group
    = f.label "name", "Rename this drain", :class => "control-label"
    = f.text_field "adopted_name", :value => @thing.display_name.titleize, :class => "form-control"
  %fieldset.form-group
    = f.submit "Rename", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-block"

I was expecting each partial to work independently of the other.  It seems they interfere with each other.

You have three forms going here - not sure what you expect to happen - but having two forms nested under another form is not the way to go.

This has nothing to do with Rails or modals. You cannot have nested form elements in any version of HTML. Since this is invalid HTML the behavior in the browser will be very inconsistent. Inputs have a form attribute which tells it what form it belongs to and in this case the attribute can either be the outer or inner form depending on how the browser chooses to parse your tag soup.
